# Does CodeNarc work with Groovy traits?

Tags: groovy, gradle, traits, codenarc

I have a Gradle project with Groovy sources and I use CodeNarc for code quality checking.

For the first time I wanted to use Groovy `trait` and it seems that even an empty one causes CodeNarc to fail badly:

> Error from [org.codenarc.rule.formatting.BracesForClassRule]
>   processing source file
>   [C:/some/path/project/src/main/groovy/AnyTrait.groovy]
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at 
>   org.codenarc.util.AstUtil.findFirstNonAnnotationLine(AstUtil.java:1085)
>           at 
>   org.codenarc.util.AstUtil$findFirstNonAnnotationLine$39.call(Unknown
>   Source) ...

Where AnyTrait.groovy has only `trait AnyTrait { }` inside (traits with more content fail as badly as the empty one).

- Gradle 2.3
- Groovy 2.4.3
- CodeNarc 2.3

With Gradle 2.4 it fails the same way, just stacktrace is hidden.
If I disable the `BracesForClass` rule than it fails the same way on `SpaceAfterOpeningBrace` rule.

Is it a bug or a feature not yet implemented?

I raised [issue on CodeNarc's GitHub](https://github.com/CodeNarc/CodeNarc/issues/93)

Comment: I have seen this issue as well, but have not tried to track it down yet - sounds like a bug in CodeNarc. Maybe it's not quite ready for Groovy 2.4 yet. :-)

Comment: Yep, probsbly it is not ready yet. Thanks for info.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [CodeNarc GitHub](https://github.com/CodeNarc/CodeNarc/pull/108), this should be fixed.

Comment: I believe it is. I raised the issue in CodeNarc's GitHub and it got addressed: https://github.com/CodeNarc/CodeNarc/issues/93. Not sure has it been released yet, need to double check.